# Images are not uploaded to specifically created folder in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I tried to create a folder to store all my images but it will not upload on its specific upload folder inside my installed theme.

Here is my code:

```
if(isset($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']))
    {
        $num_files = count($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);//count file upload


        for($i=0; $i<$num_files; $i++)
        {
            if(!is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i]))
            {
                echo "no file upload!!";
            }else
            {
                if(@copy($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i], "/upload/".$_FILES['file']['name'][$i]))
                {
                    $path = "upload/".$_FILES['file']['name'][$i];
                    //$sql = "insert into tblImage value ('".$path."')";

                }else
                {
                    echo "cant upload";
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you're trying to upload them inside your themes folder, you might need to use this function [get_template_directory_uri()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_directory_uri/). Prefix it in your @copy destination to make sure its being copied to the correct path. Check out the link for more details.

Comment: i already use that function but it did not work

Comment: Do you have debugging enabled? Try error_log() after every statement to see what's happening. Try to output all variables to see where things are not working.

Comment: inside the if statement the error_log()? i tried again the get_template_directory_uri(). It jumps to else statement which is the cant upload.

Comment: Check out the documentation for error_log() in PHP and then try to output all variables in that for loop. The log file is located in your wp-content directory with name 'debug'.

Comment: Also make sure your debugging is enabled in WordPress, search for `enable debugging in WordPress` on Google

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to figure out *exactly* what went wrong because I don't know your setup, but try these things:

1. It's inadvisable to use `@copy` in this case, especially while you're trying to figure out what's going wrong. Copy will return false on failures and show other error messages in exceptional situations, unless you prefix it with `@`. If your disk is full, for example, it'll fail silently. Just `copy` is likely more useful for this.
2. Your file naming is, at the very least, difficult to decipher. Specifically, what paths are you using? PHP file operations like `copy` require precise path information. Your path, `/upload/`, which is `upload/` later, refers to something relative from some arbitrary place, that may change. To solve this, figure out a good absolute path. If you're uploading to WP uploads, start with [`wp_upload_dir`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_upload_dir/) and build from there.
3. Unless you absolutely need a **copy** of the file *from the original location* later, **move** it instead of copying it. Remember that you'd be moving it to the uploads folder, so it'd still be available later, just somewhere else. This also avails you to [`move_uploaded_file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php).
4. There are some great comments (like from @kabiir) about how to debug what you've got. It's hard to figure out *exactly* what's going wrong without some debugging information.

Try:

```
if(isset($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']); $i++) {
        $file = $_FILE['file']['tmp_name'][$i];
        error_log('source: ' . $file);
        if (is_uploaded_file($file) && isset($_FILE['file']['name'][$i])) {
            $name = $_FILE['file']['name'][$i];
            error_log('uploaded name: ' . $name);
            $destination = trailingslashit(wp_upload_dir()) . $name;
            error_log('destination: ' . $destination);
            if (!move_uploaded_file($source, $destination)) {
                echo 'failed to move file.';
                continue;
            }
            // Now $destination contains where the file was moved to.
        }
    }
}
```

This code will output to your log (or wherever else you have error logging pointed to) the source file+path, the uploaded file name and destination file+path, per file.

Unless there's something *very* special you're doing, [`wp_handle_upload()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_handle_upload) should take care of all your needs without rewriting this. When it's done, it calls the `wp_handle_upload` filter. Hook to the end of that filter's chain to do your SQL or whatever else. There are also many plugins that do what you're trying to do and save you from having to code it yourself.

As a side note, you ought not create SQL entirely by hand in WP. Use the [`wpdb`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) class, with the [`$wpdb->prepare()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Protect_Queries_Against_SQL_Injection_Attacks) function. This also allows you to use `$wpdb->prefix`, which is the prefix for your table. (You've [prefixed your table and created it according to WP standards](https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Tables_with_Plugins), right?)